# Why are utilized all the elements when the mouse cursor is shown on only one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop-down stripes whith title for posts.
When the mouse cursor is shown on only one element - all elements become active. 
Why it's happening, and how to make only one post was active.
example:http://beardhouse.com.ua/

```
//post-description slide
$(".contant").hover(function(){
$(".post-description").css({

    'left': '-5px',
    '-webkit-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    '-moz-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    '-o-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    'transition-duration': '0.3s',
});
},function(){
$(".post-description").css({
    'left': '-120px',
    '-webkit-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    '-moz-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    '-o-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    'transition-duration': '0.3s'
});  
});
```

==================================================================================

```
        <?php if(have_posts()) : ?> 
        <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

              <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <div class="stripe_part"><img src="http://beardhouse.com.ua/wp-content/themes/arbion/images/stripe_left.png"></div>

                  <div class="contant">
                   <div class="post-description"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a></div>
                   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo first_image() ?>"title="<?php the_title(); ?>"  /></a></div> <!-- /take a first image from the post -->           
              </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: this is happening because you are targeting all these elements. Use specific transversal method to target element relative to hovered element. So provide relevant HTML markup in question. No one like to go on third website to check it, at least, i won't do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.post-description` will match all elements with class post-description. You only want to do the effect on the child of the item that's hovered on. So change the selector to:

```
$(this).find(".post-description")
```

So your whole code would be:

```
//post-description slide
$(".contant").hover(function(){
$(this).find(".post-description").css({

    'left': '-5px',
    '-webkit-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    '-moz-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    '-o-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    'transition-duration': '0.3s',
});
},function(){
$(this).find(".post-description").css({
    'left': '-120px',
    '-webkit-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    '-moz-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    '-o-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    'transition-duration': '0.3s'
});  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".contant").hover(function(){
$(this).find(".post-description").css({

    'left': '-5px',
    '-webkit-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    '-moz-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    '-o-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    'transition-duration': '0.3s',
});
},function(){
$(this).find(".post-description").css({
    'left': '-120px',
    '-webkit-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    '-moz-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    '-o-transition-duration': '0.3s',
    'transition-duration': '0.3s'
});  
});
```